# SQL Server 2016 Horizontal Partitionning table?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

SQL Server 2016 what are the advantages of using Horizontal Partitions.
I want to make multiple similar tables into 1 large table.
Ex : **Progress_YearWeekNo** is name of table which is created every week dynamicaly,i want to make it 1 common Progress table with YearWeekNo column on which i will be creating partition.
It will be huge data like 10M records in one table.
 **Below are my questions?**
1.query to select from particular partition.
2.mark only 1 partition as ACTIVE and remaining as history.

As weekly new tables are created dynamically , there are more than 200 tables .So if i combine all tables and partition it will be more manageable table than having more tables of similar type.

Comment: Hi Manoj, welcome to SO.  Please have a look at SO's posting guidelines or maybe a quick tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour.  You might wan't to edit your post to be specific about your coding issue and show what you have tried so far.  This question can be edited to fit this: "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Comment: It depends on your workload but performance may regress compared to a non-partitioned table if queries do not specify the partitioning column. 10M or 100M rows is not huge nowadays. You need a more focused question which should include why you are partitioning.  Partitioning is mostly a manageability feature, not a performance feature.